# Cannot properly set visible component

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to implement Menu with select box which sets to display or not component. I have this checkbox:

```
final CheckMenuItem toolbarSubMenuNavigation = new CheckMenuItem("Navigation");
    toolbarSubMenuNavigation.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {

            DataTabs.renderTab = toolbarSubMenuNavigation.isSelected();

            // call here the getter setter and send boolean flag
            System.out.println("subsystem1 #1 Enabled!");
        }
    });
```

And I have this tabpane which I want to render only if I have selected the checkbox:

public static boolean renderTab;

```
public DataTabs()
{
}

public boolean isRenderTab()
{
    return renderTab;
}

public void setRenderTab(boolean renderTab)
{
    this.renderTab = renderTab;
}

// below this code
tabPane.setVisible(renderTab);
```

When I run the code it's not working. I also tested this:

```
DataTabs tabs = new DataTabs(); // instantiate first
tabs.setRenderTab(toolbarSubMenuNavigation.isSelected());

 public static boolean renderTab;

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();


    public DataTabs()
    {
    }

    public boolean isRenderTab()
    {
        return renderTab;
    }

    public void setRenderTab(boolean renderTab)
    {
        tabPane.setVisible(renderTab);
    }
```

But again there is no result when I run the code and I check or uncheck the checkbox.
This is the complete source code:

http://pastebin.com/tkj4Fby1

Maybe I need to add listener or something else which I'm missing?

***EDIT
Test 3***

I also tested this code:

```
final CheckMenuItem toolbarSubMenuNavigation = new CheckMenuItem("Navigation");
        toolbarSubMenuNavigation.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {

                DataTabs.toolbarSubMenuNavigation = toolbarSubMenuNavigation;

                // call here the getter setter and send boolean flag
                System.out.println("subsystem1 #1 Enabled!");
            }
        });

// class with tabs

public static CheckMenuItem toolbarSubMenuNavigation;

    public static CheckMenuItem getToolbarSubMenuNavigation()
    {
        return toolbarSubMenuNavigation;
    }

    public static void setToolbarSubMenuNavigation(CheckMenuItem toolbarSubMenuNavigation)
    {
        DataTabs.toolbarSubMenuNavigation = toolbarSubMenuNavigation;
    }

// below
abPane.visibleProperty().bind(toolbarSubMenuNavigation.selectedProperty());
```

I get NPE when I run the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can easely tell to your tab to be visible when you check the box in one line

```
yourTab.visibleProperty().bind(yourCheckBox.selectedProperty());
```

And just with this line your tabpane will be visible only when it's checked

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that solution. The check box and the tabpane are in separate Java Classes. The problem is how I can connect them to work together?

Comment: What is the problem? `classA.getTab().visibleProperty().bind(classB.getCheckBox().selectedProperty());`